"PytorchStreamReader failed reading zip archive", but downloaded file is correct
I am trying to torch.load a weights file, my_model.ckpt. The model I am working with uses resnet18, so torch.load will download its weights, specifically resnet18-5c106cde.pth, and then use it. The MWE is this:
import os
import torch


class ModelWrapper:
    def __init__(self):
        self.model_configs_directory = "some/path/configs"
        self.model_weights_directory = "some/path/weights"
        self.device = torch.device("cuda") if torch.cuda.is_available() else torch.device("cpu")

    def get_state_dict(self):
        config_path = os.path.join(self.model_configs_directory, "my_model.yaml")
        weights_path = os.path.join(self.model_weights_directory, "my_model.ckpt")

        state_dict = torch.load(
            weights_path, map_location=torch.device(self.device)
        )["state_dict"]

        return state_dict

mw = ModelWrapper()
state_dict = mw.get_state_dict()
print(state_dict)

It works on my laptop (no GPU, so the cpu device). However, when running the model on a server with a GPU, I get the following error on the torch.load line:
`PytorchStreamReader failed reading zip archive: failed finding central directory`

I have googled around a bit, and most things point to a broken download of the resnet file. But I have redownloaded it several times, deleting it from ~/.cache/torch/hub/checkpoints, and I find it hard to believe that it went wrong every time. Also, I tried using the same file that works on my laptop - and got the same error.
I tried it both with CUDA and with the CPU, also taking care to install specific versions of torch, eliminating any version mismatches or incompatibilities.
What is interesting is that initially I also had the same issue on my laptop. It turned out that my weights file, my_model.ckpt, was somehow broken, and once a colleague had provided me with a correct one, the problem went away. Sadly, the same thing does not seem to apply to the server, and to the best of our knowledge, the weights file is correct.
I also noticed that the resnet file in question is a POSIX tar archive, and not a zip file - unlike a different resnet file in that directory, resnet18-f37072fd.pth, which is a zip file. But if it works on my laptop, I guess that's fine.
Relevant versions on my laptop:
- python3.8.18
- torch==2.1.2
- torchmetrics==0.10.3
- torchvision==0.16.2

Relevant versions on the server:
- python3.8.18
- torch==2.1.2+cu121
- torchmetrics==0.10.3
- torchvision==0.16.2

Why is torch unable to work with this resnet file?

Does this answer your question? PytorchStreamReader failed reading zip archive: failed finding central directory

No, it does not. All of the answers in that post point to a corrupt file, but like I said in my post, I am almost certain that is not the case, for reasons stated in my post: multple download attempts (including a manual one), at least one of them successful on my laptop etc.
